# Surface over plain plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Is there a way to generate a figure where the surface is over the plain plot? Like in the figure below. Notice that not only the contour and countourf would be used, but something more to add the 3D surface. I'm full able to make the plot with countour and contourf, but I'd like to make something like the image.

[Surface over plain plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRce.jpg)

[image]

Comment: have you had a look at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html or https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: Sure, these 3d surface are a different kind of plot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, matplotlib has a module to perform Topographic hillshading --> https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/specialty_plots/topographic_hillshading.html

Answer (score 0):

This group made it with python, the second figure is exactly what I wanted on that time.

https://docs.gempy.org/tutorials/ch1_fundamentals/ch1_3c_topography.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-ch1-fundamentals-ch1-3c-topography-py

[image]

[This is the link to the figure](https://docs.gempy.org/_images/sphx_glr_ch1_3c_topography_002.png)